# CW structure on $P^n \mathbb{R}$(projective space)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, cw-complexes

I am supposed to show that $P^n \mathbb{R} = e_0 \cup\cdots\cup e_n$, where $e_i$ is an $i$-dimensional cell.

I also know that there is a quotient map  $S^n \rightarrow S^n/\tilde - = P^{n-1} \mathbb{R},$ where the equivalence relation identifies points on the opposite site of the sphere, but I don't understand how that helps me to build a homeomorphism $P^n \mathbb{R}= e_n \cup P^{n-1} \mathbb{R}$? What is $e_n$ and how is it constructed. Could anybody offer here a few details?

Comment: Can you  find a CW decompostion of the sphere?

Comment: In any case, I suggest you do first the case n=1, then n=2, and so on.

Comment: No, I think the reason is that I don't know how this concept of attaching something works. Could you show me an example, how this can be done?

Comment: I suggest you browse a few textbooks on the subejct and/or search online. Going for the projective spaces  if you cannot do the circle is not going to work.

Comment: Don't you think you could give me a few ideas about the circle and then I start by my own, it's actually more adjunction thing that I don't really understand.

Comment: I don't think this is a good place to do that sort of things —this is a question&answer site, really. Textbooks are the ideal tool, on the other hand: they usually have well-thought out, coherent explanations wit pictures and a consistent treatment of the theory surrounding the examples. You should also ask your instructor about this; attaching cells is important.

Comment: I mean, it's not that I would not have looked through the books, but this identification is really the first one we are supposed to do and most books don't go into details( for example Hatcher does not and I don't have any more books about topology at home) where this identification actually comes from. So maybe you could just answer my question? It would be really good to see how this is actually done.

Comment: Pick a book like Munkres, Massey, Dold, Greenberg or any of the other, introductory textbooks on topology. Hatcher is not exactly that. Trust me: if you cannot construct a circle as a CW-complex, it is really unreasonable for you to set out to construct projective spaces. You are seriously underestimating the effort that is invoved in explaining this usefully and correctly in writing —as a hint, we not all write textbooks! I will be delighted to answer whatever specific, concrete, focused question you have, but «tell me about CW complexes», which this sort of is, is not one :-|